# What is the disposal of premises?

Tags: united-kingdom, definition, interpretation, equality-act-2010

[Part 4](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/part/4) Equality Act 2010 makes extensive references to the disposal of premises. What specifically does this concern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disposal of premises is explained by the interpretation of Part 4 at [section 38](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/section/38?timeline=false) which includes:

> (3) A reference to disposing of premises includes, in the case of premises subject to a tenancy, a reference to—
>
> (a)assigning the premises,
>
> (b)sub-letting them, or
>
> (c)parting with possession of them.
>
> (4) A reference to disposing of premises also includes a reference to granting a right to occupy them

The supporting [Explanatory Notes](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/notes/division/3/4/7) include this:

> This section explains what is meant by terms used in this Part. In particular it sets out the kinds of property transactions meant by “disposing of premises” in the case of premises which are subject to a tenancy...